# Flutter Firebase Admob Integration Confusion

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob

i have been trying to show Admob ads on my flutter App since two weeks now, although the test ads are showing when test ad unit are used. but i just want to be sure i am doing the right thing. and i have separate ad unit for each page. And also my app send alot of requests everyday, at time i get 11k+ ads request but the match rate is always below 1 or even zero.
My question is that, how  do i initialize the Firebase Admob plugin, will i initialize on all the page i intend to show ads or only on the main.dart file...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise only once wherever you want to use it, usually it has to be called in the initState() of the page you want to call it in. Look at the `example` repo of `firebase_admob` https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#-example-tab-

Comment: Okay, thanks, I want to show ads on all my App pages, do i need t call FirebaseAdmob.instanse.initialize(APP_ID) in initState of all the pages

Comment: Only in the initState() of the first page of your app